# How to get a principal's role(s) using Common Expression Language?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam, common-expression-language

I am trying to create [a deny policy with terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/iam_deny_policy) to limit the power of the Roles I made in GCP IAM.

The thing is that deny policies in terraform are tied to [principals (users/groups of users)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/principal-identifiers#v2), not roles.

I wanted to know if there was a way to use the `denial_condition` in terraform so that the deny rule would only apply to the specific role I want it to affect, (or in this case the affect everyone except the admin role), but I don't know how to get the role in [common expression language](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service/docs/using-cel).

Since the deny policies work with principals, I was thinking of an alternative solution by putting all the users in groups, then attaching the roles and deny policies to those groups. But what I really want is to have the deny policy associated with a role, so that's why I wanted to see if the `denial_condition` could meet my requirement.

Curently the deny rule simply affects all users:

```
resource "google_iam_deny_policy" "account-admin-explicit-deny-policy" {
  provider = google-beta
  parent   = urlencode("cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/${var.project_id}")
  name     = "account-admin-explicit-deny-policy"
  display_name = "Account Admin Explicit Deny Policy"
  rules {
    description = "Prevent the activation of new GCP APIs - those service/api activations should be controlled by administrators."
    deny_rule {
      denied_principals = ["principalSet://goog/public:all",]
      # denial_condition {
      #   title = "Some expr"
      #   expression = "" # Check if non-admin
      # }
      denied_permissions = [
        "serviceusage.googleapis.com/services.disable",
        "serviceusage.googleapis.com/services.enable",
      ] # Limit permissions
      exception_principals = []
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use the `expression` argument in the `denial_condition` block to check for the role with role_id `account_admin_role`? (The full role ID would be: `projects/project-id-12345/roles/account_admin_role`